# Bootstrap Panel Not Displaying

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap panel and it is not displaying. Does anyone know why my code isn’tn working? I got it from the bootstrap website and I made small modifications.

￼

BOOTSTRAP CODE

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Share Something!</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <div class="form-group">
           <label>Share Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Link</label>
            <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"       value="Submit" />
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares">Cancel</a>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you are using the right version of bs, it should work fine. so make sure you are using bs v3.

Comment: @SherifSalah how do I know what version I am using? How do I ensure I am using v3? Sorry for being noobish

Comment: btw, are you using backslash in your code intentionally here?, i'll suppose you are using forward slash in tag endings in your original code!

Comment: If you are using a cdn, then it should be something like that `href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" ` .. here the version is `3.3.7`

Comment: @SherifSalah I corrected the slashes, they copied over incorrectly. Thank you.

Comment: Just make sure you are using the right version, panels doesn't exist in bs4, its replaced by cards.

Comment: @SherifSalah I will use the correct version thank you

Comment: I was having the same issue. Thanks SherifSalah

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just you need to close tag correctly and make sure you include css & js file correct for bootstrap 3 version

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Share Something!</h3>
    </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <div class="form-group">
           <label>Share Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Link</label>
            <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"       value="Submit" />
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares">Cancel</a>
         </div>
         </form>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing of div and form element is wrong.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Share Something!</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <div class="form-group">
           <label>Share Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Link</label>
            <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"       value="Submit" />
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares">Cancel</a>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: how is this an answer! .. cards replaced panels in bs4 and you are using bs4 here with panels, and it doesn't even work!

Comment: Are you sure that you know what you are taking about? .. its not working bro and it won't work cause there are no panels in bs4.

Comment: Yes in bootstrap4 no css for panels. you are right. so i changed the version